# How to convert to vb to vb.net code and How to convert to ado to ado.net

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I need Free or Share ware tools for convert the projects like vb6 to vb.net and ado to ado.net can any one help for this and can send the articles also 
thanks and Regards 
A MD I

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any tool like [vbto](http://www.vbto.net/) which can convert vb code to vb.net you have to do it manually. There are tools which will convert some code but i once tried but there were so many bugs that i had to do it manually dont waste time.
 read these articles

1. [article1](http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/46335)
2. [article2](http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2011/01/24/converting-vb6-to-vb-net.htm)

hope this will help you